# local equivalence of loop group representations

Tags: loop-spaces, conformal-field-theory, von-neumann-algebras, rt.representation-theory, reference-request

Let $G$ be a compact, simple, connected, simply connected (cscsc) Lie group, and let its smooth loop group $LG:=C^\infty(S^1,G)$. Given an interval $I\subset S^1$, we have the ***local loop group***
$$
L_IG := \{\gamma\in LG \ | \ \forall z\not\in I  \ \gamma(z)=e\}
$$
which is a subgroup of $LG$. Let $k\ge 1$ be an integer.
The level $k$ central extension of $LG$ is denoted $\mathcal{L}G_k$.
It restricts to a central extension of the local loop group that we denote $\mathcal{L}_IG_k$.

A representation of $\mathcal{L}G_k$ on a Hilbert space is called ***positive energy*** if it admits a covariant action of $S^1$ (i.e., the action should extend to $S^1\ltimes \mathcal{L}G_k$) whose infinitesimal generator has positive spectrum.
Here, the center of $\mathcal{L}G_k$ is required to act by scalar multiplication.

> **Definition 1:**
>  *Two level $k$ positive energy representation of the loop group are called **locally equivalent** if they become equivalent when restricted to
> $\mathcal{L}_IG_k$.*

The follows is believed to be true:

> **Claim 2:**
> *Let $G$ be a cscsc group and let $V$ and $W$ be any two positive energy representations of $\mathcal{L}G_k$. Then $V$ and $W$ are locally equivalent.*

---

<s>I know a paper that proves the following:</s>

> **Theorem 3:**
> *Let $G$ be a **simply laced** cscsc group and let $V$ and $W$ be two positive energy representations of $\mathcal{L}G_k$. Then $V$ and $W$ are locally equivalent.*

***Edit:** The argument in [[GF]](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-155/issue-3/Operator-algebras-and-conformal-field-theory/cmp/1104253398.full) seems to contain a mistake (on lines -4 and -3 of
page 600)*

<s>The basic ingredients that are needed
(see page 599 of [Gabbiani & Fröhlich *[Operator algebras and conformal ﬁeld theory](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-155/issue-3/Operator-algebras-and-conformal-field-theory/cmp/1104253398.full)*] for the proof) are the following two facts about positive energy representations of simply laced loop groups:

• Every level 1 rep can be obtained from the vacuum rep by precomposing the action by an outer automorphism of $\mathcal{L}G_1$ that is the identity on $\mathcal{L}_IG_1$.

• Every level $k$ rep appears in the restriction of a level 1 rep under the map $\mathcal{L}G_k\to \mathcal{L}G_1$ induced by the $k$-fold cover of $S^1\to S^1$.</s>

There are proofs in the literature, due to A. Wassermann ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806031) p23) and V. Toledano-Laredo ([here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409044) p82) respectively, for the cases $LSU(n)$ and $LSpin(2n)$, that are based on the theory of free fermions --
actually, Toledano only treats half of the representations of $LSpin(2n)$.

---

Is there a proof of Claim 2 in the literature?
How does one prove Claim 2?

Comment: probably not really helpful, but there seems to be a paper in preparation by Toledano Laredo which maybe could shed some light about this question in the B and C case

Comment: There seems to be a proof of Claim 2 in some unpublished notes, namely
in Böckenhauer and Evans "Modular Invariants, Graphs and $\alpha$-induction for Nets of Subfactors. II" on page 66 is claimed that local equivalence hold for any compact connected simple $G$ with reference 
to the unplished notes of Wassermann "Subfactors arising from positive energy representations of some infinte dimensional groups", 1999.

Comment: Many thanks to the person who sent me Wassermann's preprint.

Comment: After having a further look at his preprint, it is now my opinion that Antony Wassermann does not provide a complete proof of the desired claim. So the question is open.